# Прикрепить меню к верху страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, menu

Здравствуйте опишу проблему.

Есть блок А (с каким то текстом).
ниже идет блок Б (меню сайта).
еще ниже идет блок В (слайдеры).

Как сделать так чтобы, при прокрутке когда блок А заканчивается, меню прикрепляется к верху и больше не слетает, пока не открутишь назад.
Пример так как я хочу есть на сайте: http://boleu.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаете состояние прокрутки с помощью `var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;` и в зависимости от того виден ли блок А указываете для блока B `position: fixed;` или `position: inherit;`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById('B').style.position = scrolled > 150 ? 'fixed' : 'inherit';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.A {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
}

.B {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #66A;
}
```

```html
<div class='A'></div>
<div id='B' class='B'></div>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
<p>Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.Make ten changes at the same time, not one change ten times. Multiple selections allow you to interactively change many lines at once, rename variables with ease, and manipulate files faster than ever.</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает, но есть одна проблемка. Когда страница только прогрузилась, меню почему то закреплено в самом верху, а как только делается какая то прокрутка, то все становится как надо. В чем может быть проблема ?Сам спросил сам нашел ошибку)). Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Можно попробовать в css указать `top: 150px;` а потом при изменении позиции на `fixed` сделать `top: 0`